# Hyperlink or Picture Type resctriction of 255 characters

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a list with a column Link to Estimate which is Hyperlink or picture type.
when I give a very long url it errors saying value of field may not contain more than 255 characters. but I need to accommodate big urls more than 255 char as it a requirement from client.
[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXHwu.png)

How can I make this hyperlink column to accept more than 255 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a new column of note type or something. Then with Clientside rendering adjust the behaviour of your field so it becomes clickable. There are plenty of examples around how to do so, so just google for 'Sharepoint JSLink' or 'Sharepoint CSR'